# Call Swift/objective-c method from Applescript

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, swift, applescript

I am trying to call a swift or Objective-C API from applescript with has argument. Currently my Objective-C method looks as below -

```
- (void)updateInfoLabel:(NSString*)information;
```

I am trying to call it from AppleScript as -

```
on infoUpdate()
    current application's MyClass's alloc()'s init()'s updateInfoLabel("Hello World")
end infoUpdate
```

Any help, pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to figure this out. Below is how we can call an Objective-C method from apple script -

```
on infoUpdate()
    current application's MyClass's alloc()'s init()'s updateInfoLabel:"Hello World"
end infoUpdate
```

The important part is, we do not have to pass the argument from the bracket, instead, it has to be sent after **:** (colon)